# Asymptotic approximation inside of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Suppose we want to find
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^b f_n(x) dx
$$
for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, $a \le b$.

Suppose there is a sequence of functions $g_n(x)$ such that $g_n(x) \sim f_n(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Is this true?
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^b f_n(x) dx
 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{a}^b  g_n(x) dx
$$
Since we're integrating in a closed interval, if $f_n(x)$ (and $g_n(x)$) converge uniformly to a function $f(x)$, we're allowed to switch the order of limits and integrals and the result would be true. Also if $f_n(x)$ were monotonically increasing/decreasing in $n$, bounded, or dominated by an integrable function, we could use the monotone convergence theorem or the dominated convergence theorem. But what happens if we don't assume that?

I guess my question is if the result is true under weaker conditions than what is needed for switching the order of the limit and the integral.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What precisely is meant by "$g_n(x) \sim f_n(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$"?

Comment: Good question. What I had in mind is $\lim_n f_n(x)/g_n(x) = 1$ for all $x$. Maybe we would need some sort of uniformity for it to be true? (of the sort that there is a $\delta > 0$ that works for all $x \in [a,b]$).

Comment: Pointwise convergence on a compact set does not imply uniform convergence. Consider $f_n=nxe^{-nx}.$

Comment: Yes, we need some uniformity. Without uniformity, counterexamples are easy to find.

Comment: So maybe my question doesn't make much sense, then. I thought my scenario could be different in that the substitution of an asymptotically equivalent expression is made inside of the integral, so maybe the result was true even if the exchange of operations wasn't warranted (because there isn't uniform convergence of $f_n$ to some function $f$, we don't have a dominating function, etc.). All the counterexamples I know of (like the one @AlexS provided) are not of this kind. For instance, take $g_n$ in Alex's example to be $n x$ times the Stirling approximation of $e^{-nx}$.